# Visual Studio 11 Beta Designer View does not open and throw an error

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-2012

I have installed Visual Studio 11 Beta. it was working fine. Two days ago i tried to install Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate RC online. It was installed correctly but not shown in my programs. then i uninstall it and re install VS11 Now The error comes when i Open my Project the designer view doesn't show the GUI. and shows my below errors.

```
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

I searched on google but didn't got how to fix it. I think it is the version error. But don't really know how to fix it.

I made a new project windows forms C# application. and stuck with same problem. 
I also uninstalls the VS11 and then reinstall it. but receives same error.

Could anyone please solve my problem.

**Please please please. I have alot of work already. I will be really really thank full.. PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP!!!**

Comment: Can you go back to a restore point?

Comment: There is only one restore point saved which is set by VS11 installer. if i restore it it will simply uninstall VS11. means affected program is only VS11 and its components. if i do so. i am sure that i'll not get rid of this problem. because i am facing this problem since 2 days. The resotre point name is "Install DirectX". Any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem in Visual Studio 2010, too.
This error suddenly disappeared as we switched to Visual Studio 2012 RC.

This could be a help to get your work done. So try to install it again.
But I'm really interested to have an official statement from Microsoft, saying this bug is fixed in VS2012.